# Angular posts whole data to Django view as key in QueryDict

Tags: angularjs, django, python-2.7

I am using **Angular 1.4.4** and **Django 1.8**. When i post data from Angular to Django view it comes in the form of whole data as key in the QueryDict.

So in view in debug mode when i evaluate request.POST it returns this

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"messagetitle":"","value":"","valueam":"","wrong_response":"","stop":"","messagekind":"1","undefined":"","messagetype":"3","state":"","language_id":1}': [u'']}>
```

Notice posted data is inside u'' as key and its value is [u'']

Angular **dataservice** code is this

```
function createDraft(data) {
    return $http({
        url: view_url + 'create_draft/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
}
```

**Controller** code

```
app.controller('message',function($scope, $ngBootbox, dataservice, $http){
    $scope.formData = {
        "messagetitle":"", "value":"", "valueam":"",
        "wrong_response": "", "stop": "", "messagekind": "1",
        "undefined_response": "", "messagetype":"3",
        "state": "", "language_id":1
    };
    saveDraft = function(){
        dataservice.createDraft($scope.formData).then(
        function(res) {
            $ngBootbox.alert("<div class='alert-success alert_box'>Draft Saved</div>")
        },
        function(res) {
            var error_message = res['statusText'].trim();
            if (error_message === '')
                error_message = 'Error Occurred';
            $ngBootbox.alert("<div class='alert-warning alert_box'>" + error_message + "</div>")
        })
}
```

**saveDraft** function is called from angular template(which is html form) on button click.

Let me know what i am doing wrong here. I have tried some answers on stackoverflow but could not find any question/answer which addresses my specific problem.

**PS:**
I know i can do json.loads(request.body) but i need to post data in django's request.POST

Comment: Use request.POST.get('key_name')

Comment: It returns None

Comment: Please show what `data` is and where it comes from.

Comment: I have updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.param(data)` instead of data in your service